# Load file error on Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm following along with a tutorial on testing with Rspec. Getting a syntax error when trying to run the test. Here's my test code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CommentsController, type: :controller do
  describe "comments#create action" do
    it "should allow admins to create comments on posts" do

        post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)

        admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
        sign_in admin

        post :create, params: { post_id: post.id, comment: { message: 'awesome post' } }

        expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
        expect(post.comments.length).to eq 1
        expect(post.comments.first.message).to eq "awesome gram"

    end

    it "should require an admin to be logged in to comment on a post" do
        post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
        post :create, params: { post_id: post.id, comment: { message: 'awesome post' } }
        expect(response).to redirect_to new_admin_session_path  
    end

    it "should return http status code of not found if the post isn't found" do
        admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
        sign_in admin
        post :create, params: { post_id: 'SUNSHINE', comment: { message: 'awesome post'} }
        expect(response).to have_http_status :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:create]

  def create
      @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
      return render_not_found if @post.blank?

      @post.comments.create(comment_params.merge(admin: current_admin))
      redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def render_not_found(status=:not_found)
      render plain: "#{status.to_s.titleize} :(", status: status
  end

  def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:message)
  end
end
```

Here's the terminal output when running the test:

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWM7M.png)

What's odd is that when I comment the lines that are producing the error, the tests run as intended with the last test passing. I've checked the test file along with similar posts that describe the same problem and it looks to me like the syntax is correct. New to Rails so pardon the rookie mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a variable named `post`:

```
post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)   # define `post` variable
post :create, params: ...          # try to call `post` method
```

Therefore, on subsequent lines `post` will refer to the variable, not the `post` method.

**Solution 1: Rename the variable**

```
my_post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
post :create, params: { post_id: my_post.id, ... }
```

**Solution 2: Use `self.post` to access the method**

```
post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
self.post :create, params: { post_id: post.id, ... }
```

---

Replicating the issue in `irb`:

```
def foo
  "bar"
end

foo = "wat"
#=> "wat"

foo :hello
# SyntaxError: (irb):63: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
# foo :hello
#      ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with you defining a variable named `post` then trying to call the `Rspec` method `post`:

```
it "should require an admin to be logged in to comment on a post" do
  post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
  post :create, params: { post_id: post.id, comment: { message: 'awesome post' } }
  expect(response).to redirect_to new_admin_session_path  
end
```

Try re-naming it:
to call the `Rspec` method `post`:

```
it "should require an admin to be logged in to comment on a post" do
  message = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
  post :create, params: { post_id: message.id, comment: { message: 'awesome post' } }
  expect(response).to redirect_to new_admin_session_path  
end
```

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I have a post model so I was conditioned to typing that in for all of the tests. Thanks!